# Is there an automated way to add conversion="true" tag?

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

I am onboarding a new SFMC account and none of their links have been set up as conversion tracking links and this is a request of theirs. Is there a way, possibly using %%_AdditionalEmailAttribute%% to automatically append this tag to all URLs? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the href tag when you set `conversion="true"`

```
<a href="http://www.northerntrail.com/productlist.asp" conversion="true">www.northerntrail.com/productlist.asp</a>
```

The system adds query parameters to your link to be used in the [xml conversion call](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_implement_conv_tracking.htm&type=5)

[The string is as below:](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_conversion_landingpg.htm&type=5)

> PARAMETER  VALUE
>
> j  -   Job ID (identifier of this email)
> sfmc_sub - Subscriber ID
> l (lowercase L) -   List ID
> u   - ID of the landing page URL
> jb -    Job batch ID
> mid - Your account number (member ID)

```
http://www.example.com/landing.asp?j=JobID&l=ListID&sfmc_sub=SubscriberID&u=LinkID&jb=BatchID&mid=MemberID
```

If you don't want to set the `conversion ="true"` you could update the WAC string to pass these values